# Optional Route Params in Silex

Tags: php, routes, silex

I've done some looking and can't seem to figure out how to have an optional parameter in a URL segment in Silex. So I have this route currently:

```
    /{controller}/{method}/{param}
```

The param wildcard is what I'd like to be optional. So this pattern would pick up URLs like

```
    "Controller1/Method1" and "Controller2/Method2/Param"
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just set up the processor for the longest URL possible (having all the parts, including optional ones), like this:

```
$app->get('/controller/{method}/{param}', 
    function($method, $param) {
      // called both by `/controller/some-method/some-param-string`,
      // `/controller/some-other-method`, and even `/controller`
});
```

By default, empty strings are assigned as values of the params that correspond to the omitted URL parts. But you can override this explicitly, as described in [**the doc**](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#default-values):

```
$app->get('/page/{pageName}', function($pageName) {
  // ...
})->value('pageName', 'index');
```

Now, when `/page` is accessed, `$pageName` is set to `'index'`.